# Remove Span from API

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

How can i remove `<span class="pull-right"></span>`from API?

[image]

Here is my dataSrc. My quantity needs to be right-aligned.

[image]

Here is the table footer. Table footer needs to compute the total quantity in the table. It works fine but when i add right align, the result goes like this

[image]

Comment: Change to ``typeof i === 'string' ? $(i).text()*1 :``

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this is a problem.  You return int from an API, which works, but you want it right-aligned - so you've added HTML to the API now you want to remove HTML from the result of the API.  Instead, remove the HTML from the API, then, *where you want the formatting* add the HTML - ie when you add it to the table.  Or just format the table.  Why can't the table have formatting and not the API?

Comment: @freedomn-m, i just start my coding with web last month so im not good as you expected :( but what you said is noted. thanks again.